# When do the events of "Heir to the Jedi" and the marvel star wars comic take place in relation to each other?

Tags: star-wars

I understand that both take place in the period between *A New Hope* and *Empire Strikes Back*, but when do they take place in relation to each other?

I also understand that they are similar levels of canon, but they have different levels of Luke's skills in the force, so which comes first in the timeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Wookieepedia page for [Heir to the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Heir_to_the_Jedi#cite_note-Kevin_Hearne_Tweet-4) there is this quote

> Author Kevin Hearne has stated that Heir to the Jedi takes place prior to the Marvel comic book series Star Wars.

This was apparently a twitter reply by the author. ([image source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Heir_to_the_Jedi#Notes_and_references) from Wookieepedia)

[image]